# relationship between Minkowski addition and the trajectory of a numerical controle machine?

Tags: soft-question

This is a very naive question about the Minkowski addition. I hope not to be off-topic.

I read in the [Wikipedia's article dedicated to it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_addition#Numerical_control_.28NC.29_machining) :

> In numerical control machining, the programming of the NC tool
>   exploits the fact that the Minkowski sum of the cutting piece with its
>   trajectory gives the shape of the cut in the material.

I don't understand the relationship "cutting piece + trajectory = the shape of the cut in the material" .

By example, if I look at the first image of the article (blue+green = red)
[image]

... I don't get it : where would be the cutting piece ? what about the trajectory ?

Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: You might be confused, because that's not quite true. Let $A$ be the shape of the cutting tool, and $P$ the trajectory of the cut. The shape of the cut is the sum of the translations of $A$ along the curve $P$. Minkowski sum gives you something similar, but not exactly, for example if $A$ is a circle of radius $1\mathrm{unit}$ and $P$ consists of edges of a square of size $10\mathrm{units}$, then the cut would be a rounded-corner square of size $11\mathrm{units}$ with the thickness $1\mathrm{unit}$ while the Minkowski sum will get you thickness $2\mathrm{units}$ and size $12\mathrm{units}$.